# Docker run with project path

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I’ve created docker file and image which build OK,
In addition in my docker file I added

`WORKDIR  /project`

And when I run `docker run -i -t ctr`

I see in the command line:

`ctr@442329f0d2:/project$`

I need to run commands on project like `/project/myapp`

when building the image I use `COPY /myapp /project`

and now the project is located under project/myapp and I was able to run it,

the issue here is a bit more tricky as I need to provide the project `myapp` when I **run the docker** and not during the build,
and it can be any project, How can I provide a project to `workdir /project` during the command `docker run -i -t ctr`
 ? 
or any other suggestion how to run the docker with context of project with application

**In short:** in `docker build` I  build the applications environment and now to test it I want to "move/provide" app (any app) when I run the docker image to the `project`  (workdir) context 
which basically copy my local app `myapp` to the context of the docker `/project` when I run it

Comment: Can you include your entire `Dockerfile` in the question?  Generally you set this up to package an entire single application, and run it when you `docker run` the container (the bash prompt you show suggests you're missing the `CMD` line to start the program); if you have multiple applications then you build multiple images out of them.

Comment: @DavidMaze - the `cmd` is not missing :)  as I need to run the commands explicitly , think of running `npm install` on project , you are using in the docker `node` image but here the tricky thing is that you want to pass the project druing the `docker run` and it's not contained inside the docker image ...

Comment: Why do you want it run in Docker at all?  In the workflow you're describing I'd just run Node, not the Docker `node` image.

Comment: @DavidMaze - we need it as part of our CI ...this is not a question :)

Comment: @DavidMaze - think of docker which have (for several app type) `all` the dep and now you want to build those app with this docker